# Question on convergence of integrals.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on $X$ having finite total variation. Let $B(X)$ be the set of all complex valued bounded Borel measurable functions on $X.$ Let $f_{\alpha}, f \in B(X)$ be such that $f_{\alpha} \to f$ pointwise and $\sup\limits_{\alpha} \left \{\left |f_{\alpha} (x) \right |\ |\ x \in X \right \} \lt \infty.$ Then show that $\int f_{\alpha}\ d\mu \to \int f\ d\mu.$

We have $$\left | \int f_{\alpha}\ d\mu - \int f\ d\mu \right | = \left |\int (f_{\alpha} - f)\ d\mu \right | \leq \int |f_{\alpha} - f|\ d |\mu|.$$  Now how does the given conditions conclude the result?

**EDIT** $:$ If we have a sequence instead of a net then we are through by the virtue of DCT. But I don't have any idea whether DCT holds for pointwise convergence of a net of measurable functions which are uniformly bounded by an integrable function.

Comment: If the net is additionally monotone, then the answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656902/a-monotone-convergence-theorem-for-nets-in-reed-and-simon-vol-i?rq=1). Note that DCT does not hold for nets.

Answer (score 1):

Without further assumptions this cannot hold. A counterexample is given in the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141198/a-net-version-of-dominated-convergence).
If one additionally assumes that $(f_\alpha)_\alpha$ is *monotone*, then the conclusion is true, and a proof may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656902/a-monotone-convergence-theorem-for-nets-in-reed-and-simon-vol-i?rq=1).